# show each subquery results in record?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two subquery each one have a 2 columns but with different values.

how to show this differrnt results in just one.

Q1:

```
select
city
,length(city) as le
from station
where length(city) in 
    (select min(length(city)) from station)
order by length(city) asc , city asc 
limit 1
```

output:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| HHH | 3 |

Q2:

```
select
city
,length(city) as le
from station
where length(city) in 
    (select min(length(city)) from station)
order by length(city) asc , city asc 
limit 1
```

output:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| bjhg | 4 |

the needed output

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| HHH | 3 |
| bjhg | 4 |

Thanks

Just questions and need a support

Comment: Combine the two queries with `UNION`.

Comment: Your two queries are the same. Why do they return different results?

Comment: How does your Column A magically change from 'bjhg' to 'HHH'???  It's the exact same query.

Answer (score 0):

```
(
select
city
,length(city) as le
from station
where length(city) in 
    (select min(length(city)) from station)
order by length(city) asc , city asc 
limit 1
)
UNION ALL
(
select
city
,length(city) as le
from station
where length(city) in 
    (select min(length(city)) from station)
order by length(city) asc , city asc 
limit 1
)
```

Comment: as long as the columns are the same, you can use UNION to unite your results